# Object of curretUser - Is it safe

Tags: security, object, memory-safety

I am sitting programming an "atm/internetbank" as a school assignment and i am wondering the "safety" of creating an object where you save a currentUser. The "atm" should be able to run at a laptop.
To this "atm" assignment there is a related database. When you log-in with a matching username and password it saves the info with balance to the User object as currentUser. My question is, how safe is the password and especially the balance. Is it possible to manipulate with the info outside the program.
Thinking of just getting the balance when needed directly from the database and directly updating the balance when something new has happened.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First ATMs and web banks are different in that ATMs assume physical security of the client while web sites have little physical security.

That said, just get everything from the server as you need the data. Feel free to keep data in a server side session object. I guess during some data in memory on the client is safe but there probably isn't a need.

Comment: And test twice all data receive from user. Think like on other side is devil - not user : )